# How do I prevent my text from being placed on each other?

Tags: android, android-layout

How do I fix this layout, I am trying to create a chat UI but my textviews are on top of each other if I enter a lot of text. I tried setting margins and paddings but it did not solve my problem. Could someone help me. Thanks in advance.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/message_profile_image"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/receiver_message_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/message_profile_image"
        android:background="@drawable/receiver_messages_layout"

        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sender_messsage_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="sender messages hello how are you teoggogo0dogo0go0wegewwg"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="@+id/receiver_message_text"
        android:background="@drawable/sender_messages_layout"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add   android:layout_below="@+id/receiver_message_text" to sender_messsage_text TextView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `layout_bellow` / `layout_above` of `RelativeLayout`

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/sender_messsage_text"
        android:layout_below="@id/receiver_message_text"
        .../>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with the correct usage of

> RelativeLayout

and

> android:layout_below

.
Your updated xml should look like below in order to achieve as explained in the question.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/receiver_message_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/message_profile_image"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/receiver_messages_layout"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="RECEIVER"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sender_messsage_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/receiver_message_text"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sender_messages_layout"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="SENDER"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/message_profile_image"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```